# Python - Projecteuler 8

Tags: python

Im stuck at Eulerproblem 8 (I know im a noob ;) ).

> The code gives me the error: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

```
num = long("""
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450""".replace("\n", ""))
multiples = []
def biggest_multiple_of_4_adjacants(number):
    for i in range(len(str(number)) - 3):
        multiples.append(long(str(number)[i]) * long(str(number)[i + 1]) * long(str(number)[i + 2]) * long(str(number)[i + 3]))
    return max(multiples)

print(biggest_multiple_of_4_adjacants(num)
```

Comment: Surely the error message would've pointed this out to you?

Comment: I don't know about `multiples` but you are missing a parenthesis at the very end.

Comment: Even if you fixed the trailing parentheses I get this error `NameError: name 'long' is not defined`

Comment: Yeah i changed long back to integer.. somehow thought the number would be to big to be stored as an int so i thought why not try as a long..

Comment: This seems like a ludicrous way of doing things - you convert the `str` to a `long`, then keep converting it *back to a string* inside the function. This is **hugely** inefficient!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Is there a better way to get the nth interger of a number?

Comment: The way you're doing that is fine, but why not just *leave it as a string*? You call `str(number)` **five times** for every digit in the number, but *never actually use it as a number*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`print(biggest_multiple_of_4_adjacants(num)`

to:

`print(biggest_multiple_of_4_adjacants(num))`

You ate `)` at the end of of the line